# Server and Client getting different GCM registration id for same device and app

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I am tracking down a potential race condition with GCM token updates and wanted to ask if anyone knows what happens in this scenario.

Suppose that I have a server named pushDelivery that sends pushes via GCM and an Android client named X.  X tells pushDelivery what it's push token is each time a user foregrounds the application.

1. X launches, retrieves it's token, "A", from the Google servers and then tells pushDelivery to store it's token
2. pushDelivery stores the token A
3. pushDelivery sends a message to X and receives an updated GCM token (canonical registration ID​), "B", from the Google servers.  pushDelivery replaces A with B
4. X launches, retrieves it's token from the Google servers

The question is this:  In step 3, does X receive token A or B from the Google servers?
My concern is that if X receives token A then pushDelivery will end up overwriting B with A.  The next time pushDelivery sends a push to X it will overwrite A with B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the "X" app shouldn't register to GCM each time it enters the foreground. It should only register once when it's first launched, or when first launched after an udpate is installed.

As for your "step 3", if the GCM server returns a canonical registration ID, it only means that your app failed to give your server the latest registration ID it got from Google, or that your server failed to persist the latest registration ID or to delete a previous registration ID of the same device. GCM doesn't change the canonical registration ID on its own. It can only be changed due to a GCM registration invoked by the client app (and even in that case the registration ID normally stays the same, unless you unregister and register again).

Therefore, to answer your question, after your server gets a canonical registration ID B from Google, any registration to GCM done at the client app should yield the same registration ID B (unless, for some reason a newer registration ID is created). The old registration ID A will not be returned to your client app by GCM.

Comment: about a previous registration id, the following link [link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical) states that "Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will stop working." I wonder if you know any reliable documentation about when the previous registration id will store working.

Comment: @EricLeon I haven't seen any such documentation, and from experience, all the old registration IDs I have still work.